# Can anyone recommend me a good to-do application?

Tags: software-recommendation, thunderbird

In previous Ubuntu versions like 10.04, we used to have Evolution and its calendar/to-do options. Now we have Thunderbird and I am not sure whether I can have the same options on it.

Can anyone recommend me a good native application that offers calendar and to-do/organizing features? I am in a serious need of some organization here.

Thanks.

Comment: You can just install Evolution and remove Thunderbird if you want.

Comment: Maybe Google Keep and Google Calendar? Though they're not native and they're sort of separate. (So I'm not bothering to post a full answer.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try using ['NitroTask'](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/awesome-task-management-app-nitro-tasks.html). It is a simple, nice, and very useful To do list management apps.

It has these features, I was looking for a long time:

- Simple addition and deletion of task
- Theme support, include 5 themes. *(awesome feature)*.
- Task synchronization with [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com) and [Ubuntu one](https://one.ubuntu.com/) *(Cool!!)*
- Multi Language support
- Sort by Title, Date or Priority. *(very handy if you have a long list)*
- Custom default background image support. *(Can be used for killing boredom)*

To install it, use these command by opening a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> shortcut.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cooperjona/nitrotasks
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nitrotasks
```

<sup>This is currently available for Ubuntu 11.10, 12.04 and 12.10</sup>

I think, you will enjoy this software.

Here is a screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: worked fine for me i am using [lubuntu13.10](http://lubuntu.net/)

Comment: Tasks vanishing from application after shutdown, don't know whats the reason but its frustrating.

Comment: @tiGer, might because of some bug? Not using this now. I currently use [Trello](http://www.trello.com).

Comment: Throwing an error for Ubuntu 16.04.
Err:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cooperjona/nitrotasks/ubuntu xenial Release    
  404  Not Found
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: @Richie That's because maybe the application isn't being maintained anymore for Xenial and higher releases. You can try the other suggestions or highest version debs from here http://ppa.launchpad.net/cooperjona/nitrotasks/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nitrotasks/

Comment: It is not maintained anymore. The repository gives 404 error.

Comment: @ErayTuncer The question was from 2012. It's not fair to give downvote just because the software isn't maintained. Just use other suggestion

Answer (score 15):

## The command line

Let's not forget the commandline for managing tasks

```
sudo apt-get install task
$ task add some very important task
$ task
```

[image]

You can also install `vit` if you want an alternative UI to this list. There are also some command line tools for managing your agenda.

Comment: how do i remove a task or mark as complete?

Comment: `task <filter>  done` where filter is the filter you use to select a task, see the man page

Comment: This is pretty neat if you can remember all the commands for it. Very useful no nonsense app.

Comment: Note that it is `sudo apt-get install taskwarrior` now.

Comment: Does not work in Ubuntu 22.01.
E: Unable to locate package task

Answer (score 6):

Since Wunderlist native linux client is not maintained anymore good alternative is [**Wunderlis**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wunderlist-for-chrome/ojcflmmmcfpacggndoaaflkmcoblhnbh) Package app for Chrome/Chromium (it doesn't require Google Chrome to run to be able to    use it).

- The Wunderlist Packaged App also features voice input (you can
  dictate your to-dos) and has the ability to work offline.
- It's simple and easy to use, supports timed reminders, recurring
  to-dos (although its recurring feature is definitely lacking),
  separate reminders from the due date of the task, notes and
  additional info associated with your to-dos, shared to-dos with
  others, multiple categories, and more. You can star important tasks
  (but that's as close to priority as you'll get), and customize the
  look of the app. It's broad platform support—and its webapp—mean
  you'll always have access to your to-dos.
  [image]

Another good alternative is [**Any.do**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/anydo/ocgddccilgpeepgglnlpchkpgamkgmld) Package app.

- Breaking things down into "Today", "Tomorrow", "Upcoming", and
  "Someday" allows you to really make sense of just what needs to
  happen when.
- Visual priority markings, and notes (which themselves act as sub task
  lists) makes the app even better. But the real cream of the crop
  aspects are the "Plan Your Day" daily review of the lists.
  [image]

Answer (score 4):

Just install Evolution:

Or open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type `sudo apt-get install evolution`.

Comment: Alright, I did install Evolution... However, I don't see the to-do thing on the calendar menu. Could you please point me to a way that I can do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are reading this in 2017, I think it's worth checking out [Everdo for Linux](https://everdo.net/linux).

pros:

- beautiful and pleasant to use, which is still rare on Linux
- a true desktop app - doesn't require login/internet and stores data locally
- low friction UX, optimized for GTD

[image]

cons:

- not open source
- not native application (electron based app)

Answer (score 2):

Getting Things GNOME is very simple and quite nice.

Or run this in the Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gtg
```

Answer (score 2):

[Wunderlist](http://www.wunderlist.com/) is awesome! I used [these instructions](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/how-to-install-wunderlist-in-ubuntu.html) to install it and it was easy and painless. The desktop app syncs with Android, iOS and the web. Can't as for much more than that!

Answer (score 2):

**The built-in To Do app is the best!**
I know it comes with Ubuntu 18.04, Ubuntu 19.10 and Ubuntu 20.04.

It's simple, organized and looks nice.

Possible to:

- add Notes, Due Date and even Priority for each todo
- schedule todos (which then appear in notification bar I think)
- categorize by any group
- see a list of all todos scheduled for today
- sync to a mail service (like Gmail)

[look how nice: screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNcPQ.png)
(a list of todos under digital-orientation list )

Answer (score 0):

If you like Thunderbird, I would simply suggest that you give a try to Lightning, the calendar/task manager for Thunderbird.
You will find it here: https://addons.mozilla.org/thunderbird/addon/lightning

Answer (score 0):

Good to-do application should be always available and visible. Something like [Rainlendar](http://www.rainlendar.net/cms/index.php):

[image]

or [Calendar indicator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wkq4UI5CNYM) perhaps? It can synchronize with Google calendar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest one:
[Todo.txt demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxHfG.jpg)

It operates with just one text file that's controlled by you, and makes it easy to check off items on your to-do list without needing to open a full-bodied text editor or dive into the command line.

[Todo.txt Indicator for Ubuntu Helps You Get Stuff Done](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/03/todo-txt-ubuntu-indicator-applet)

Answer (score 0):

The best app multi-platform for managing events and tasks is Taskcoach.

http://www.taskcoach.org/

If you want to use Thunderbird you can use the extensions Lightning (for events) with Todo.txt (tasks)

Answer (score 0):

**Remember The Milk**
It is a great app that I recently discovered.
Remember The Milk has two versions, free and Pro.Some of the main features:

- Organizing tasks in plain text lists
- Divide bigger tasks into subtasks
- Add tags, due dates, estimated time, links, and notes to tasks
- Tag locations in Google Maps then use them to organize tasks
- Sharing individual tasks or lists with contacts
- Weekly schedule of tasks
- Integration with various services such as Gmail, Evernote etc.
- Desktop notifications

Installing Remember The Milk in Linux is available via the binaries provided. To download the .deb package, you have to log in first to [their website](https://www.rememberthemilk.com/services/linux/)

**CREDITS:** [itsfoss](https://itsfoss.com/remember-the-milk-linux/)